# Binding a nested ListBox to a nested List?

Tags: wpf, listbox, itemtemplate

I have the following ViewModel-Property:

```
public List<List<string>> Names .... //It's a dependency property
```

In my view I would like an `ItemsControl` that has an `ItemsControl`:

```
 <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Names}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ?????}">
                    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Label Text="{Binding ??????}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                </ItemsControl>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
```

How can I bind to the items of the `List`? In code sampel above I marked it with `?????`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simply use  binding to the current Binding Source:

```xml
ItemsSource="{Binding}"
```

See some comments below:

```xml
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Names}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <! -- Here is the current binding source will be inner
                      List<string> 
                -->
                <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}">
                    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

                    <! -- Here is the current binding wource will be 
                          a string value from the inner List<string>
                    -->
                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Label Text="{Binding}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                </ItemsControl>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
```